# How will we invite the Shekhinah?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, messiah, shechinah

Is there a tradition brought down about what we will do to invite the Shekhinah to rest once we have completed and inaugurate the Bayt Hamikdash?

Comment: (1) What did we do to invite the Shekhinah to rest once we completed and inaugurated the previous Batei Mikdash? (2) Why wouldn't we be able to do any of those for the next Bayt Mikdash? (3) Will we need to [do anything to] invite the Shekhinah to rest once we have completed and inaugurate the Bayt Hamikdash?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there's at least one tradition that the Shechina is still with the various communities of Jews in exile, and just returns along with them. [Megillah 29a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.29a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Yerushalmi Taanit 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Taanit.1.1.17). [Shemot Rabbah 2:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.2.2) contains a dispute between R' Shmuel bar Nachman and R' Eliezer about whether the Shechina departed to heaven after the destruction of the temple or whether it stayed there: the Midrash seems to decide against the first opinion and say that it is still present at the Western Wall today.

The Tanya [Iggeret Hakodesh 25](https://www.sefaria.org/Tanya%2C_Part_IV%3B_Iggeret_HaKodesh.25.21-22) explains that exile involved drawing down the innermost parts of holiness (which Israel is attached to), into the lower parts by which the Shechina always sustains the nations, thereby strengthening them further. In [Likkutei Torah, Re'eh 19c](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14963#p=371&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=), the effect of this is that, although the Shechina is now hidden in the form of exile, we can still unveil it when we withstand the trials of this exile. These trials are described in [Gevurot Hashem 40.2](https://www.sefaria.org/Gevurot_Hashem.40.2?lang=bi). See also [Derekh Mitzvotecha, Maamar 16:2](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=16082#p=383). [Earlier, the Maharal says](https://www.sefaria.org/Gevurot_Hashem.39.4), this is reflected in the fourth parshah of tefillin/kriat shema "Vhaya im".

Instead of the idea that "we will do" something to bring the Shechina, the [Zohar Emor III:90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar,%20Emor%2011:37) explains that, because the Shechina, the presence of Hashem, moves out of exile with us, the redemption is both dependent on and belongs to Hashem, not Israel.